# Is it possible to group files in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

If I have an Android project with all of the classes in the same package, is there a way in the IDE to group those files visually without moving them to new folders.

For example, in Xcode I can have several .m files in the same directory, select them all, and select New Group From Selection. This will make it look like they're all in one folder without actually moving any of the files.

In the example below, file1.swift, file2.swift, AppDelegate.swift, and ViewController.swift are all in the same directory, but visually grouped in the Project Navigator.

[image]

Note: I can't move the files into their own packages or I'd just do that. :)

Comment: Why can't you move them into their own packages?  Its a quick and easy refactor, Android Studio will do the hard work for you.  If its because you made use of protected functions and variable access, then you have an unmaintainable mess anyway.

Comment: I'm creating a library with a lot of internal classes and need to be able to have only the actual API visible to the developer who is using the library, so they have to all be in the same package so they can be package-private.

Comment: The answer there is generally just to give them documentation on what they can and can't use.  If they really want to access private functionality, they can anyway (its trivial to decompile and change private to public, and barely more work to do it at runtime via reflection).  Packages are the answer here.  Especially as doing it in the UI of your IDE won't be portable between multiple developers, whereas packages provide organization for everyone working on the code.

Comment: Thanks. Guess that's what I'll have to do. I'm not as concerned about the library being decompiled. I was just hoping to simplify the interface as much as possible.